Bitbucket Repo clone error SSL connection timeout Error for Bitbuket
I am trying to clone the repo from my bitbucket using VS code. While cloning the repo from VS code, i am getting an error unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/projectname/reponame.git/': SSL connection timeout
I am not able to find the appropriate steps. I am using macOS. Also, I have configured the app password into the bitbucket setting
Thank you for help
I have tried to follow the steps fatal: unable to access : Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Connection timed out

Can you access Bitbucket on that system from a browser?

Yes i can access the bitbucket from a browser
